# Get public or base directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When you use base_path() or public_path() , the result contains bootstrap/.. or bootstrap/../public because the path is taken from the bootstrap/paths.php file. Is there any method to get only the real base path?

ex : /homepages/0/d271770356/htdocs/ or /homepages/0/d271770356/htdocs/public

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a function for this called [realpath()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php).  However it's not necessary in most cases as the file functions usually work with `..` fine.